# How to get the source of images inside div react native

Tags: javascript, regex

I have regular expression for extracting the source of images in html string coming from json api in react native app.
The output is in array:

```
var m,
array= [],
str = '<img class="d-block mx-auto" src="http://www.website.com/759x493.jpg" />,
rex = /<img[^>]+src="?([^"\s]+)"?\s*\alt="First slide">/g;
      while ( m = rex.exec( str ) ) {
          array.push( m[1] );
      }
console.log(array);  // ["http://www.website.com/66189-759x493.jpg",...]
```

However I want rex that gets only the source of images inside specific class carousel-item :

```
str = '<div class="carousel-item"> <img class="d-block mx-auto" src="http://www.website.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/66189-759x493.jpg" />';
```

I can not use DOMParser like other solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE 2020-06-04:** This code snipped is updated based on new info on source string:

This regex populates an array with image links within carousel-item divs:

```js
var imageUrls = [];
var str = '<div class="carousel slide">\n' +
  '  <div class="carousel-inner">\n' +
  '    <div class="carousel-item active">\n' +
  '      <img class="d-block mx-auto" src="http://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/66189-759x493.jpg" />\n' +
  '    </div>\n' +
  '    <div class="carousel-item">\n' +
  '      <img class="d-block mx-auto" src="http://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/66174-1-778x493.jpg" />\n' +
  '    </div>\n' +
  '  </div>\n' +
  '</div>';
var re = /<div class="?carousel-item"?[^>]*>\s*<img [^>]+? src="?([^"\s]+)/g;
str.replace(re, function(m, p1) {
  imageUrls.push(p1);
});
console.log('result: ' + imageUrls.join(', '));
```

Note: The parenthesis in `([^"\s]+)` capture the image URL, which is passed on by `p1` parameter in the replacement function.

Comment: The part captured in my regex contains the image URL, which can be referenced by `$1`. I turned the example into a runnable code snippet, and anchored the regex for clarification. Please verify operation by running it. Also, clarify if you have a different input, or need a different output.

Comment: Yes it works fine for the string str, but in my real response it returns the string html itself

Comment: Well, we can help you only if you provide an actual string you have.

Comment: Hello here is the link for string html https://justpaste.it/6q7eh

Comment: Ok, I updated the code snippet based on you info, please run to verify. For next time please supply sample input ahead of time